# <span id="sample">0</span> to new input box

Tags: javascript, rangeslider

I recently have a result in a modal from `calculatesum` JavaScript displayed as `<span id="sample">0</span>` (the value will increase based on the number key in by users)

How do I display this final sample value in another input box outside of the modal? Help?

JavaScript as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });

});

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

HTML or `rangeslide` code as below:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control slider-text-field" id="homeContentInput" placeholder="250,000">
                </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;(RM)</td></tr></table>
                <br/>
                <input type="range" value="250000" min="15000" max="500000" step="10000" id="homeContentRange">
                <span class="slider-label-min">RM 15,000</span> <span class="slider-label-max">RM 500,000</span>
```

Basically, I need to replace `placeholder="250,000"` for the first input box and `value="250000"` with the final value from `<span id="sample">0</span>`.

Comment: Basically, I need to replace placeholder="250,000" for the first input box and value="250000" for the 2nd input box, with the final value from <span>

Comment: You had a selector `$(".txt")` but nothing seems to be having css class called `.txt`? Whats that?

Comment: It's actually to calculate the sum for values key in as below.
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-1" value="0"><br>
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-2" value="0"><br>
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-3" value="0">

Comment: I have difficulties seeing through your code. Can you post an example or use jsfiddle?

Comment: please try to be more specific and clear. it seems what ever is your problem or whatever you are trying to achieve is not clear from the description provided by you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this right but I think you want something along these lines?

I assume you want

- the first field readonly
- the second field as the slider
- on submit calculates the total, in which you can post the results in another div.. In your case a modal.

---

Place the result where ever you like

```
<p id="result"> </p>
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="text" value="250000" readonly="readonly"/>
<span> + </span>
<input id="value2" type="text" id="textInput" value="15000">
                <span class="slider-label-min">RM 15,000</span> <span class="slider-label-max">RM 500,000</span>
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<p id="result"> </p>
<input type="range" type="range" value="250000" min="15000" max="500000" step="10000" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function output(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById('value1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('value2').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parseInt(value1) + parseInt(value2);
}

function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('value2').value=val; 
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
//handler to trigger sum event
$(".txt").each(function() {

  $(this).keyup(function() {
    calculateSum();

  });
});


function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });

  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  //$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(0));
  $("#homeContentInput").val(sum.toFixed(0));
  $("#homeContentRange").val(sum.toFixed(0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
*****************************************************************
<br>if you just want to add up the values then this will work, else you need to be more clear with your question.
<br>form2-1:
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-1" value="0">
<br>form2-2:
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-2" value="0">
<br>form2-3:
<input class="txt" type="text" id="form2-3" value="0">

<br>Not sure what you want to do bellow this... *****************************************************************
<br>

<input type="text" class="form-control slider-text-field" id="homeContentInput" placeholder="250,000">(RM)
<br>

<input type="range" value="250000" min="15000" max="500000" step="10000" id="homeContentRange">
<br>
<span class="slider-label-min">RM 15,000</span>  <span class="slider-label-max ">RM 500,000</span>
<br>*****************************************************************
```